# resetting the image counter on a Panasonic DMC-G2

Tags: panasonic

I found out by trial/error that the "RESET COUNTER" doesn't allow you to reset the image counter, it just increments it to the next largest group of 1000 photos (e.g. from P1000xxx -> P1010xxx -> P1020xxx). I'm stuck at P113, and I want to either set it to P2000000 without having to RESET COUNTER 87 more times, or reset it to zero.

There must be some way to do this: where is the info stored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aha, I figured it out. The logic used by the DMC-G2 camera for the "RESET COUNTER" appears to be:

1. Increment the group `nnn` (P100, P101, etc.) by 1.
2. If the photo `Pnnn0001.JPG` does not exist, set the photo counter to this image and stop.
3. Otherwise, increment the group `nnn` by 1. (Wraparound '999' -> '100')
4. If we haven't tried this group # before, go to step 2.
5. Otherwise, give up and don't reset the counter.

So to reset the counter to 200, just create directories 100_PANA, 101_PANA, 102_PANA, ... 198_PANA, 199_PANA each with one file in it.

To reset the counter to 100, create directories up through 999_PANA *without* any 100_PANA directory present.

I wrote a script with [jsdb](http://www.jsdb.org/) to do this on my Mac:

```
function pana_reset_help(root,firstnum,lastnum) {
  for (var i = firstnum; i <= lastnum; ++i) { 
    var d=root+'/DCIM/'+i+'_PANA'; 
    system.execute('mkdir '+d);
    // now write a dummy file 
    // to prevent the RESET COUNTER from using this dir
    var S = new Stream(d+"/P"+i+"0001.JPG","w"); 
    S.writeln(); 
    S.close(); 
  };
}

// example run: pana_reset_help('/Volumes/sd7',113,199);
```